# Código ISO para países bálticos. Configuración HREFLANG correcta

Tags: html, web, seo, href

A la hora de configurar la etiqueta `hreflang`, ¿alguien sabe si existe un código ISO que agrupe los países bálticos? No he encontrado nada ni en la documentación de [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=es) ni en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#BA).

El caso es el de un dominio con una versión con un contenido en inglés enfocado a Europa (ejemplo.eu) y un subdominio con contenido en inglés enfocado solo a Lituania, Estonia y Letonia (baltic.ejemplo.eu).

Por ejemplo:

- `<link rel='alternate' href='https://ejemplo.eu' hreflang='en-EU' />`
- `<link rel='alternate' href='https://baltic.ejemplo.eu/en-xx/' hreflang='en-xx' />`

Mi duda es qué poner en las "xx" del atributo `hreflang`.

Gracias de antemano. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

[Según w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/struct/dirlang.html)

> Two-letter primary codes are reserved for [ISO 639](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/references.html#ref-ISO639) language abbreviations
>   ...
>   Any two-letter subcode is understood to be a [ISO 3166](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970917/references.html#ref-ISO3166) country code.

Por lo tanto `en-EU` está mal. EU no es un país válido según ISO 3166, sino simplemente un código reservado. Lo correcto sería apuntar todos los países angloparlantes de europa apuntando al mismo sitio (te pongo sólo tres ejemplos):

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-GB" href="http://ejemplo.eu/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-IE" href="http://ejemplo.eu/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-IM" href="http://ejemplo.eu/" />
```

Para los países bálticos no hay tal cosa como un código de región reservado pero, como dije antes, aunque lo hubiese no te sirve un código de región.

Ahora bien, los idiomas oficiales de Lituania, Estonia y Letonia son respectivamente, según ISO 639, el lituano ([lt](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?iso_639_1=lt)), el estonio ([et](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?iso_639_1=et)) y el letón ([lv](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/langcodes_name.php?iso_639_1=lv)), pero nada te impide juntar un prefijo ISO 639 con un país que hable otro idioma, así que puedes hacer:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-LV" href="http://baltic.ejemplo.eu/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-LT" href="http://baltic.ejemplo.eu/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-EE" href="http://baltic.ejemplo.eu/" />
```

¿Qué efecto puede tener esto en el SEO de la página? Si tu página con subdominio `baltic` está en inglés, tal vez rankee mejor para las búsquedas en los países bálticos, pero igual tendrá un alto bounce-rate si el visitante no habla inglés.